# How to cut webdriver.io log(query DATA part)?

Tags: automation, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I have a problem with webdriver.io loglevel setting. If I set logLevel: info (or debug or trace) I see all get/post queries. If I set loglevel less verbose (warn/error) I don't see any query. What I want is to cut DATA part of the log to let's say 50 symbols.  [image]
Where to dig for a solution. Should I override a logger or some EventListener class(to implement onPost method and add my custom logging)? If yes, then which one?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option at the moment. You can raise a feature request or pull request to https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio

There are some other options that might not work for you as well: set logger level to WARN for webdriver logger or write all logs to file.

Comment: Thanks. Warn level is too concise for me. I thought it might be some event listener and I could override 'onPost' method to do custom logging

Comment: It should be quite easy to implement it in webdriverio. Ex add a config key to suppress these messages. It would help if you can raise an issue